# CFML using StructFindValue() to find and replace string values inside of a structure

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

**Question:** How can I use the `path` value that `StructValueFind()` returns to assign a new value to the key `path` points to?

I'm looking to search all values in a structure for a specific string and then replace that string with a different value.

I am able to find all occurrences of the string I'm searching for using `StructFindValue()` which returns an array of structures with the keys `key`, `owner`, and `path`. I would assume that the `path` would allow me to set a new value/replace the found string.

According to [Adobe's CFML 9 documentation for `StructFindValue()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f04.html), the `path` value is...

> Path: string which could be used to reach the found key

But I can't find anywhere how to use the value of `path` to reach the found key, and specifically assign a new value to that key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to mess around with the path: the result from `structFindValue()` returns a direct reference to the sub struct in question already (in the `owner` key).

So this sort of thing should do the trick:

```
<cfscript>
st = {
    top={
        middle1={lower1="value1",lower2="value2"},
        middle2={lower3="value3",lower4="value4"}
    }
};
writeDump(st);

value = structFindValue(st, "value3");
writeDump(value);

value[1].owner[value[1].key] = "new value";
writeDump(st);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @Adam

Comment: Nice one. Haven't used before. Seems like a powerful function. But is it safe (performance wise) to use?

Comment: @Pankaj my philosophy is that anything is safe to use - performance wise - until there's evidence to suggest it's a problem. I am unaware of any issues.